# gdb debugging arm app. under windows

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, arm

Hi i want to debug my programms which are cross compiled on windows for arm architecture by using the codesourcery gcc.

I have the following things debugging:

sam-ice jtag/jlink debugger
arm-none-eabi-gdb

when i use the command line inteface arm-none-eabi-gdb programm.elf i cannot run the programm under windows.
under eclipse i get some error "warning: RMT ERROR : failed to get remote thread list."

has anyone eyperience on these things or can help fix the problems?

Comment: Did you start the JLink remote server that talks to GDB? Did you tell GDB to connect to a remote target?

Comment: well the gdbserver is running on the target board, when i am in console i start gdb with just "arm-none-eabi-gdb". then i connect to server <gdb> target remote localhost:2331. seems like i am connected, i can run and halt the processor, but i cant set breakpoints.

Comment: (gdb) target remote localhost:2331 -

Remote debugging using localhost:2331 - 

0x00000000 in ?? () -

(gdb) break main -

No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command. -

Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n -

(gdb) continue -

Continuing. -


and nothing happens

Comment: ok sometimes i can continue the programm but i seem to miss the source file for inserting break points

Comment: ok i got it fixed need to load the elf files with the gdb